# How to add a default value to EditText: android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText which returns an empty string on calling `edittext.getText().toString()`. Instead of returning an empty string, I want to set a default value for this result and i don't want that value to be shown in EditText. Is it possible to do so? If yes then how can i do that?

Comment: you can just concat the default string with your `edittext.getText().toString()`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not something `EditText` can do for you, you can always extend `EditText` and add this behavior:

```
public class MyOwnEditText extends EditText { ... }
```

Override `getText()` to return the default value, if there's en empty `String` returned by default implementation:

```
@Override 
public Editable getText() {
  Editable text = super.getText();
  if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
    return text;
  }
  return new SpannableStringBuilder("default-text");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do so?

No, sorry, `EditText` does not offer that feature.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to deal with this is to use the [ternary operator](https://www.sitepoint.com/java-ternary-operator/)

```
String emailString = this.email.getText().toString();
return TextUtils.isEmpty(emailString) ? "your default string" : emailString;
```